# Detect empty shelves using image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Given an image, how can I create an algorithm using image processing techniques to identify the sections where there are no products present. I also need to create a bounding with coordinates for the empty spaces where products are not present.
I need to accomplish this using OpenCV. And I cannot use Deep Learning here.

I have used a Canny edge detector, and empty spaces are well identified using this.
Should I use a Contour on the results of the Canny edge detector?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please show any relevant code, and provide actual input images next to the desired outputs, e.g. manually drawn.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do that in image processing technique by using Matlab, vector images.

1. Use two images.
2. One is with empty shelves.
3. Second one is the current image.
4. Subtract 1st image from second second.
5. You will get the results how many shelves are empty.